# One way ANOVA by hand

Tags: statistics, mean-square-error

I am trying to do an ANOVA by hand to the following data.

```
Summer   83 85 85 87 90 88 88 84 91 90
Shoulder 91 87 84 87 85 86 83
Winter   94 91 87 85 87 91 92 86
```

I have calculated

$y_{i.}=871, 603,713 $ and $y_{..}=2187, N=25,n=3$

From here I was able to calculate the $SS_T = 220.24$ but I keep getting an unexpected value for $SS_E$

I am doing

$\sum \frac{y_{i.}^2}{n} -\frac{y_{..}^2}{N} = \frac{871^2 +603^2+713^2}{3}-\frac{2187^2}{25} = 352220$

and I am very puzzled why I get such a big number (according to SAS I am supposed to get 35.61)
I have done similar problems before and the exact same method worked out.

May I have some help, please?

I am suspecting that the observation numbers being unbalanced is the issue...

Notice that:

$$y_{i.} := \sum_{j=1}^n y_{ij}$$ and 
$$y_{..} :=\sum_{i=1}^a\sum_{j=1}^n y_{ij}$$

Comment: What is $y_i$? What is $y$? It is wrong to assume that all the people which know ANOVA use the same notation that you use...

Comment: I am learning this for the first time, so I apologize for the notation.  $y_. = \sum_{j=1}^n y_i$ and $y_{..}=\sum_{i=1}^a \sum_{j=1}^n y_{ij}$

Comment: @hyg17 Maybe edit the question instead of explaining in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of groups. In your case $n=3$.

Let $n_i$ be the number of samples in each group. In your case, $n_1 = 10, n_2 = 7, n_3 = 8.$

Let $\mu_i = \frac{y_i}{n_i}$ be the mean of each group.

Let $\mu = \frac{y}{N}$ be the mean of the whole sample. Notice that $N = \sum_{i=1}^n n_i = n_1 + n_2 + n_3$.

By definition, $SS_E$ is the sum of squares of the errors between the mean of each group $\mu_i$ and the whole population mean $\mu$, weighted by the cardinality of each group. Formally:

$$SS_E = \sum_{i=1}^n n_i(\mu_i - \mu)^2.$$

We can work on this expression:

$$SS_E = \sum_{i=1}^n n_i\left(\mu_i^2 - 2 \mu_i \mu + \mu^2\right) = \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n n_i \mu_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^n n_i \mu \mu_i + \sum_{i=1}^n n_i \mu^2 = \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n n_i \frac{y_i^2}{n_i^2} - 2 \mu \sum_{i=1}^n n_i \frac{y_i}{n_i} + \mu^2 \sum_{i=1}^n n_i  = \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i^2}{n_i} - 2 \mu  \sum_{i=1}^n y_i + \mu^2 N .$$

Notice that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = y.$$

Therefore:

$$SS_E = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i^2}{n_i} - 2 \mu y + \mu^2 N = \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i^2}{n_i} - 2 \frac{y}{N}y + \frac{y^2}{N^2}N = \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i^2}{n_i} - \frac{y^2}{N},$$

which is different and more correct than your formula.

---

Summing up, your problem is that you are using $n$ (which you defined as the number of groups) instead of the number of samples in each group, i.e., $n_i$.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you so much.  I have been struggling with this for a week now!